# React Custom Dropdown Within Card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox, dropdown, jss

I've inherited a framework in React using `react-jss` and `simple-flexbox` for styling. The `CardComponent` image is displayed below. I created a `GroupComponent` to fit inside this card.

What I would like to do now is, when a user clicks on a row, a list of n rows is revealed, which subsequently extends the card and pushes the other entries further below the size of the list (basically a burger menu push, or similar to a dropdown). I'd also like functionality to delete and add to these rows.

I have very little experience of component styling outside of using `react-bootstrap` for most things so am really stuck here.

Here's `GroupComponent`:

```
const useStyles = createUseStyles((theme) => ({
    itemTitle: {
        ...theme.typography.itemTitle,
        color: theme.color.veryDarkGrayishBlue
    },
    itemValue: {
        color: theme.color.grayishBlue2
    }
}));

export const GroupComponent = ({ containerStyles, teams }) => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const classes = useStyles({ theme });
    function renderEntry(title, value) {
        return (
                    <Row horizontal='space-between' vertical='center'>
                        <span className={classes.itemTitle}>{title}</span>
                        <span className={[classes.itemTitle, classes.itemValue].join(' ')}>
                            <img
                                src={require('../../assets/images/' + value + '.png')}
                                alt={value}
                                height='16'
                                width='16'
                            />
                        </span>
                    </Row>
        );
    }

    return (
        <CardComponent
            containerStyles={containerStyles}
            title={'Group ' + teams[0].groupName}
            items={[
                renderEntry(teams[0].name, teams[0].name, 0, 0),
                renderEntry(teams[1].name, teams[1].name, 0, 0),
                renderEntry(teams[2].name, teams[2].name, 0, 0),
                renderEntry(teams[3].name, teams[3].name, 0, 0)
            ]}
        ></CardComponent>
    );
};

export default GroupComponent;
```

Here is the list of entries that I would like displayed and push the other countries down the card:

```
{
"players": [{
            "playerId": 1,
            "name": "Balotelli",
            "teamId": 1,
            "goalPercentage": 0.18,
            "numberOfGoals": 0
        }, {
            "playerId": 2,
            "name": "Baggio",
            "teamId": 1,
            "goalPercentage": 0.12,
            "numberOfGoals": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

And finally here is the `CardComponent`. If you can imagine the `players` array appearing as a dropdown and pushing the rest of the country rows further down:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would add the n rows of extra content inside a container, inside renderEntry:

```
function renderEntry(title, value) {
  return (
    <Row horizontal='space-between' vertical='center'>
      <div className="main-content">
        <span className={classes.itemTitle}>{title}</span>
        <span className={[classes.itemTitle, classes.itemValue].join(' ')}>
          <img
            src={require('../../assets/images/' + value + '.png')}
            alt={value}
            height='16'
            width='16'
            />
        </span>
      </div>
      <div className="extra-content">
        <div>Player 1</div>
        <div>Player 2</div>
        <div>Player 3</div>
      </div>
    </Row>
  );
}
```

then to hide the div I would create a css class that sets the height to 0, when an optional *hidden* class is added to any `<div className="extra-content">`;

```css
.extra-content.hidden {
  height: 0;
}
```

I would then add a css animation to make the height change smooth:

```css
.extra-content {
  transition: height 1s;
}
```

Then add a click event handler to each `renderEntry` which would add or remove the **hidden** class:

```js
function renderEntry(title, value) {
  const hideContent = (e) => {
    e.target.querySelector('.extra-content').classList.toggle('hidden');
  }
  return (
    <Row horizontal='space-between' vertical='center' onClick={hideContent}>
```

And lastly you could set it up so that the hidden class is added as standard:

```
<div className="extra-content hidden">
```

[See example on codepen](https://codepen.io/huwfernie/pen/gOMyEgv)